# Flutter - FlutterTest conflict with http.get and Mockito

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In flutter test, when using `mockito` package with testing for http service, adding

```
http.Client client
```

as parameters to the function is required.

Instead of `http.get(***url***)`, now it is `client.get()`.

`client.get()` works fine with testing. However, this does not work and return error as in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `http.get()`, one client will be created in the `get()` function, and it automatically closes when service ends.

By adding http.Client parameter to the function, the test can be functioning.

http.get() is not used because http is difficult to mock according to flutter.

Also, according to flutter, live web service is not used/recommended in testing because it is not stable and potentially slow.